# Read *.wab files in 64-bit Win 7 Pro

Tags: 64-bit

Looking for a 64-bit reader of *.wab files as I have now upgraded to 64-bit Win 7 Pro and I cannot access my addresses.  Stupid, I know.....didn't do my homework!!!!!

Is there anything that can help me open, read, convert these files ?

Thank you very much.

Sam.

Comment: i think you should add more tagging, then a more specialized audience will find your question

Answer (score 0):

A free and quick way :

Double click on wab file then click **import**

then run **wab.exe** ,and you will see your imported contacts.